# Syntax highlighting not working on AndroidManifest.xml, but it's fine on every other XML file (Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

So this is strange.  My syntax highlighting is not working on my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  It's rendering as if it's just a plain text file.  All of my other XML files get syntax highlighted just fine, but this particular file is plain white and black.  Any idea why that could be?

I've tried closing the file, restarting Eclipe.. nothing fixes it.  I'm using Android Development Tools with Eclipse 4.3.1

Comment: Are you sure `AndroidManifest.xml` is opening in the right editor? Right-click on it and check the `Open With` menu.

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml here so we can check it too.